# Pi Pico W (Micropython) - How to enable CTRL+C via UART?

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, uart, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'd like to remotely control my Pi Pico W using HC-05 or HM-10. It works in general, but in case of infinite loops (like "While" loop), sending CTRL+C via UART does not stop the loop.

It works via USB, but not if I use UART. I use DUPTERM to duplicate REPL on UART0 of my Pico W.

Peter

I tried both HC-05, HM-10. Webrepl also uses dupterm and does not allow me to interrup infinite loops using CTRL-C.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at the MicroPython for RP2 source code here:

https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/ports/rp2/main.c

As a first step, it looks like you will need recompile MicroPython with the `MICROPY_HW_ENABLE_UART_REPL` option enabled.  This setting could go in your board configuration file, for example in `ports/rp2/boards/RPI_PICO_W/mpconfigboard.h`.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there is any difference between MICROPY_HW_ENABLE_UART_REPL and dupterm.

Is there a way to recompile MicroPython online?

Comment: Before you get into recompiling anything, are you sure the Ctrl-C character is making it over the Bluetooth link? You could try a test program on the Pico that receives bytes from the UART pin and prints their value to the console to see exactly what is being received; and/or you could try connecting to the UART pins with a USB-TTL serial adapter for a wired connection.